# Animating imageviews with autolayout and a mask

Tags: swift, animation, autolayout, masking

I'm trying to animate a stram of images in a view using auto layout.

The animations are coming along nicely. However, I need the image be masked by the view they are animating in, they must not run off but must be cut off. This I just cannot figure out. Can anybody show me the light?

[image]

Comment: Your question needs much more detail if you want to get help. Please review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

if u want a mask you can set:

```
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```